# Создание DatePicker android java

Tags: java, android

[image: ДатаПикер]

Всем привет, возник важный вопрос, а как же можно создать такой пикер в Android studio на Java?

Comment: Именно такой, полагаю, с помощью сторонних библиотек.

Comment: Есть примеры данных библиотек? Буду очень благодарен если скинете.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, Вы ищете то, что называется WheelPicker.
Можно найти разные библиотеки на gihub, которые можно использовать в своем проекте. Некоторые из них:

- [SingleDateAndTimePicker](https://github.com/florent37/SingleDateAndTimePicker)

[image]

- [react-native-wheel-picker-android](https://github.com/nyur321/react-native-wheel-picker-android#date-picker)
  [image]
- [WheelPicker](https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker)
  [image]